# Counting primitive operations, Big O Notation

Tags: java, primitive, operations

Say I have a `int` variable called `count`, I was wondering how many primitive operations are int the statement:

```
count++;
```

Would it be 3? Because if you write it out in a different form, such as:

```
count = count + 1;
```

It has 1 read, 1 operation, and 1 write. So that would mean the statement `count++` counts as 3 primitive operations right?

Comment: After the code has been optimised to machine code it might be just one instruction

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it may be seen as having 3 operations.
That means it is a constant number of operations, so for Big O notation, it is the same as if there were only 1 operation or 10, as long as it is constant.

Answer (score 0):

On most processors (or virtual machines, since you tagged your question with "java" tag) there is special instruction for incrementing value by some small amount.

i.e. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings - iinc

Therefore I'd count simple increment as 1 primitive operation (although internally it still gets executed as read-increment-write).